# Javascript : How to write a regex to check if a symbol is surrounded by space for all occurences

Tags: javascript, regex

The colon ':' in the sentence should be surrounded by space for all of its occurrences.

I have a string  "Yes I Do : things that have:fun"

My regex should return false, I have tried the below which is checking is checking first occurence, if found it is returning true.

```
/(\s:\s)/.test("sd : sds:sds")
```

Comment: If `fun :` a valid input? (line ending with `:`)

Comment: @anubhava, No its not a valid input ,however I'm doing that check if startswith or endswith

Answer (score 3):

If you want a pure regex solution then use this alternation based regex **to find out invalid inputs**:

```
/(?:^|\S):|:(?:$|\S)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RPeTSY/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:^|\S)`: Match start or a non-whitespace
- `:`: Match a colon
- `|`: OR
- `:`: Match a colon
- `(?:$|\S)`: Match end or a non-whitespace

```js
const regex = /(?:^|\S):|:(?:$|\S)/;
const arr = [`Yes I Do : things that have :fun`,
`Yes I Do : things that have: fun`,
`: fun`,
`fun :`,
`Yes I Do : things that have : fun`,
` : fun`,
`fun : `];

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(regex.test(arr[i]), '::', arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the exact opposite, search for the symbol which is surrounded by a non-space character(either before or after symbol).

```
!/\S:|:\S/.test("sd : sds:sds")
```

Comment: Nope. It didn't work for !/(\S:\S)/.test("sd : sds :sds"). It returns true for this.

Answer (score 1):

Add the global flag *(`g`)* to the end of your RegEx and check for non-space chars.

```js
console.log(!/\S:|:\S/g.test("sd : sds:sds"));
console.log(!/\S:|:\S/g.test("sd : sds : sds"));
```

This will check the full string.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by regex and simple logic. This is not the proper way to achieve use case but maybe it can help.

```js
function check(str) {
  let reg = / : /gi;
  let match = str.match(reg);
  if (match && match.length == str.split(":").length - 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false
  }

}
console.log(check("sdf : sdf"));
console.log(check("sdf: sdf"));
console.log(check("sdf : sdf:"));
console.log(check("sdf : sdf sdfds : sdf"));
```